# Find list within a string

Tags: python, csv

I see lots of examples of finding strings within strings, or finding strings within lists, but how do I find a list within a string. For example I have a csv file with columns of data and the last column is either a string or sometimes it is a list. Here is a subset of data showing just the last 3 columns.

```
TRUE, 93877, S26476961
TRUE, 93878, ['S26489167', 'S26492524']
FALSE, 93879, S26476962
FALSE, 93880, ['S26489168', 'S26492527', 'S26492528']
```

At first I was trying to parse each entire line of the csv file at the comma but it parses the commas within the list (creating extra columns). I just want the list to be recognized as a singular piece of data so I can work with it as a list of 'n' items.
@TemporalWolf 's comment helps greatly because if I use the csv module (specifically csv.reader) as so ...

```
reader = csv.reader(inFile)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

It keeps the list in a single column. Now the problem remains that it is just a string. In other words, `row[n][0]` returns the left bracket (`[`) but I want to make that into a list.

Comment: use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library

Comment: Also, consider using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: Try splitting on commas not followed or preceded by the character `'`: `[re.split("(?<!'), (?!')", line) for line in open(filename)]`.

Comment: (a) What do you want to do with the data afterwards? (b) What would you say to making the first line, for instance, into: TRUE, 93877, ['S26476961'] or,  in other words, all lines end with lists?

Comment: @BillBell that would be ok if all of the last column's values were lists (in some cases single item lists).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This relies on the `'` character with which the elements of your list are quoted. Using this information, it only splits on commas not followed or preceded by that character, using regular expression:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import io


text = """TRUE, 93877, S26476961
TRUE, 93878, ['S26489167', 'S26492524']
FALSE, 93879, S26476962
FALSE, 93880, ['S26489168', 'S26492527', 'S26492528']"""

with io.StringIO(text) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.split("(?<!'), (?!')", line.strip()))


# ['TRUE', '93877', 'S26476961']
# ['TRUE', '93878', "['S26489167', 'S26492524']"]
# ['FALSE', '93879', 'S26476962']
# ['FALSE', '93880', "['S26489168', 'S26492527', 'S26492528']"]

# Or with pandas

with io.StringIO(text) as f:
    print(pd.read_csv(f,
                  header=None,
                  sep="(?<!'), (?!')",
                  engine='python'))

#        0      1                                        2
# 0   True  93877                                S26476961
# 1   True  93878               ['S26489167', 'S26492524']
# 2  False  93879                                S26476962
# 3  False  93880  ['S26489168', 'S26492527', 'S26492528']
```

#### Edit:

If you are using python2, you will need to convert the text to unicode (by placing the character `u` before the text) to be able to use `io.StringIO`:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import io


text = u"""TRUE, 93877, S26476961
TRUE, 93878, ['S26489167', 'S26492524']
FALSE, 93879, S26476962
FALSE, 93880, ['S26489168', 'S26492527', 'S26492528']"""

with io.StringIO(text) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.split("(?<!'), (?!')", line.strip()))


# ['TRUE', '93877', 'S26476961']
# ['TRUE', '93878', "['S26489167', 'S26492524']"]
# ['FALSE', '93879', 'S26476962']
# ['FALSE', '93880', "['S26489168', 'S26492527', 'S26492528']"]

# Or with pandas

with io.StringIO(text) as f:
    print(pd.read_csv(f,
                  header=None,
                  sep="(?<!'), (?!')",
                  engine='python'))

#        0      1                                        2
# 0   True  93877                                S26476961
# 1   True  93878               ['S26489167', 'S26492524']
# 2  False  93879                                S26476962
# 3  False  93880  ['S26489168', 'S26492527', 'S26492528']
```

#### Edit 2:

If you do not wish to rely on the presence of the quote character `'`, you can try the following:

```
import ast
import re


with io.StringIO(text) as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = re.split(", (?=\[)", line.strip())
        line = []
        for part in parts:
            if all(char in part for char in ('[]')):
                line.append(ast.literal_eval(part))
            else:
                line += part.split(", ")
        print(line)
```

You split on the commas positioned before the left square brackets, and then inspect the result as follows:

1. Check if each element of the list generated from the split operation has square brackets. If so, then convert it to a `list` object with `ast.literal_eval` and add it to the final output list.
2. Otherwise, split on the commas and add the ensuing list to the final output list.

This should get the same thing as the above solutions.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying this but it returns this error ...
    `Traceback (most recent call last):`
     `File "C:/path/To/script.py", line 11, in <module>`
        `with io.StringIO(text) as f:`
    `TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str`

Comment: You must be using python2. See the changes

Comment: That's amazing! Works in Python 3. Have never seen something like `sep="(?<!'), (?!')"` is a good idea..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fun solution: Split each line on commas and try to parse each section as Python code. If it's invalid, this means that we are not including the entirety of a list:

```
import ast

def get_columns(line):
    def valid(code):
        try:
            ast.parse(code.strip())
        except SyntaxError:
            return False
        return True
    sections = line.split(',')
    columns = []
    for i, section in enumerate(sections):
        if i == len(sections) - 1 or valid(section):
            columns.append(section)
        else:
            sections[i + 1] = ','.join([section, sections[i + 1]])
    return columns

with open(inFile) as f:
    for line in f:
        for column in get_columns(line):
            print(column)
```

As this does not involve regular expression for your exact case, this is quite general. Also note that since none of the "code" in your data file is ever evaluated to perform the tests, this is totally safe.

Works with Python 2 and 3.

Comment: trying this one as well. Currently getting an IndexError on the else line ...
`for column in get_columns(line):`

Comment: Surely not for the text data you provided?

Comment: Yes it seems to print everything now. I'm just still not able to isolate that string that looks like a list and make it work like a list. It is helpful though.

Comment: A cheap and dirty way to get your list would be to check for the `[` character and use `eval`:

    if column[0] == '[':
        my_list = eval(column)

Answer (score 0):

This is the reversed approach. It finds the lists in the data returned by `csv.reader` by checking for leading `[` and trailing `]` in the row's items.

```
import csv 

def find_lists(row):
    sublist = []
    for item in row:
        if not sublist:
            if item.startswith('['):
                if item.endswith(']'):
                    yield [item[1:-1]]
                else:
                    sublist.append(item[1:])
            else:
                yield item
        else:
            if item.endswith(']'):
                sublist.append(item[:-1])
                yield sublist
                sublist = []
            else:
                sublist.append(item)
    for item in sublist:
        yield item

with open('test.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        print(list(find_lists(row)))
```